# Override create method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

New to drf.I have json input data like below:

```
{
"name":"df",
"email":"d@gmail.com",
"age":"21",
"gender":"Male",
"phone":"234",
"total_price":86,
"advance":0,
"due":86,
"selected":[{"id":8,"name":"sdf"},{"id":9,"name":"dg"}]
}
```

Below is my views.py.I want to override create method for the json input data.But no idea how to do it.

```
class PatientEntry(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        many = isinstance(request.data, list)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data,many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, headers=headers)
```

serializers.py:

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    test_id = models.IntegerField()
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)
    advance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    due = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Patient')
```

From selected key,
"selected":[{"id":8,"name":"sdf"},{"id":9,"name":"dg"}]

id should add in test_id field and name should add in test_name field

Comment: What do you want to do ? Your method is already overriden.  What is not working ?

Comment: can't save data.status 400. This is the response i am getting {""test_id":["This field is required."],"test_name":["This field is required."],"total":["This field is required."]}

Comment: Well, share your Serializer. It means that you put them with required=True ...

Comment: I edited my question and add serializer.py and models.py .please check

Comment: Well because your serializer is based on your model only, you need to share your model

Comment: Now you can manipulate your `Model`.  Change the fields to add `blank=True` and either `null=True` or `default=blah` like `phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`  or `role = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Patient', blank=True)`

Answer (score 0):

ModelSerializer will guess required field through your models. Because your models define required properties, the serializer field also have them as required.

To override this, you need to either loose requirements on your models, either tell the serializer to overide the 'required' = True:

```
class Meta:
    model = YourModel
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_kwargs = {'mymissingfield': {'required': False}}
```

Comment: I am passing all the fields value so I don't need to make required field False.Maybe the problem is with selected key in json data.Which is passing a list

Comment: The error message AND your input shows that test_id, test_name and total are not in your json.

Comment: But I am passing those by this from selected id will be add in test_id and name will be add in test_name field.  "selected":[{"id":8,"name":"sdf"},{"id":9,"name":"dg"}]

Comment: Well your serializer is based on your model. If your model have extra fields, you need to exclude them in your serializer. so you must remove them for your serializer. And because you want to add them to your model, you need to add the "selected" fields in your serializer, define it as an object, and update the create method of this serializer.